# Browser array size limit to 100 elements

Tags: javascript, browser

I am getting values from a log in Splunk that gives me about 20,000 IP addresses? give or take. But when I console.log the results it displays only 100 elements.

result when I do 
[console.log(JSON.stringify)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO2DA.jpg)

result when I do [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D637f.jpg)

Comment: Try updating your chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[console.log(Array(20000).join('255.255.255.255 ').split(' '))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUrLL.jpg)

It is printing all 20000 IPs array. Check.